# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended showed while creating a new table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add the following columns in my table and it keeps giving me the following error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

More Details: https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-00933

The code I used to enter is

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, Customer_Last_Name, Customer_First_Name, Customer_Middle_Name, Suffix, Phone, Email_Address, First_Seen_Date, Customer_Address_Street1, Customer_Address_City, Customer_Address_State, Customer_Address_Zip, Customer_Address_Last_Modified_Date)
VALUES
    (1, 'Roy', 'Casagranda', 'A', 'Jr', '1234567890', 'Roy.c@example.com', ('2023-APR-15'), '777 Glades Rd', 'BocaRaton', 'FL', '33431', ('2023-APR-15')),
    (2, 'Elon', 'Marley', 'A', 'Mr', '9876543210', 'Elon.M@example.com', ('2023-APR-20'), '225 20th  St', 'BocaRaton', 'FL', '33431', ('2023-APR-20')),
    (3, 'Bill', 'Door', 'B', 'Mr', '5554443333', 'Bill.D@example.com', ('2023-APR-10'), '3100 Lionshead St', 'BocaRaton', 'FL', '33431', ('2023-APR-10')),
    (4, 'Mark', 'Musk', 'C', 'Jr', '2223334444', 'Mark.M@example.com', ('2023-APR-05'), '1201 N Dixie Hwy', 'BocaRaton', 'FL', '33431', ('2023-APR-05')),
    (5, 'Bill', 'Ackman', 'B', 'Sir', '1112223333', 'Bill.A@example.com', ('2023-APR-15'), '555 Cedar St', 'BocaRaton', 'FL', '33431', ('2023-APR-15'));
```

I have also tried using the TO_DATE function and it keeps giving me the same error.

Comment: That date format looks suspect. Have you tried `2024-04-15` instead of `2024-APR-15`?

Comment: It's most likely the month name `APR` in the date value to blame. I changed it to `04` and the statement ran successfully. Although this was tested in MySQL, I doubt being fundamental sql standard it would differ in Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle's table value constructor, `VALUES`, does not support multiple rows until version 23c. Below version 23c, the statement should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, Customer_Last_Name, Customer_First_Name, Customer_Middle_Name, Suffix, Phone, Email_Address, First_Seen_Date, Customer_Address_Street1, Customer_Address_City, Customer_Address_State, Customer_Address_Zip, Customer_Address_Last_Modified_Date)
SELECT 1, 'Roy', 'Casagranda', 'A', 'Jr', '1234567890', 'Roy.c@example.com', date '2023-04-15', '777 Glades Rd', 'BocaRaton', 'FL', '33431', date '2023-04-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Elon', 'Marley', 'A', 'Mr', '9876543210', 'Elon.M@example.com', date '2023-04-20', '225 20th  St', 'BocaRaton', 'FL', '33431', date '2023-04-20')   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Bill', 'Door', 'B', 'Mr', '5554443333', 'Bill.D@example.com', date '2023-04-10', '3100 Lionshead St', 'BocaRaton', 'FL', '33431', date '2023-04-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Mark', 'Musk', 'C', 'Jr', '2223334444', 'Mark.M@example.com', date '2023-04-05', '1201 N Dixie Hwy', 'BocaRaton', 'FL', '33431', date '2023-04-05'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Bill', 'Ackman', 'B', 'Sir', '1112223333', 'Bill.A@example.com', date '2023-04-15', '555 Cedar St', 'BocaRaton', 'FL', '33431', date '2023-04-15'   FROM DUAL;
```

If the above format is not suitable, you could also achieve the same result with the `INSERT ALL` syntax.

I also converted the date-like string into date literals. Date literals use a standard date format of YYYY-MM-DD, whereas a string implicitly converted into a date will use the sessions (unreliable) default date format.

Answer (score 1):

Later versions of Oracle does not support inserting multiple values, instead try inserting one by one

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, Customer_Last_Name, Customer_First_Name, Customer_Middle_Name, Suffix, Phone, Email_Address, First_Seen_Date, Customer_Address_Street1, Customer_Address_City, Customer_Address_State, Customer_Address_Zip, Customer_Address_Last_Modified_Date)
VALUES (1, 'Roy', 'Casagranda', 'A', 'Jr', '1234567890', 'Roy.c@example.com', ('2023-APR-15'), '777 Glades Rd', 'BocaRaton', 'FL', '33431', ('2023-APR-15'));
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, Customer_Last_Name, Customer_First_Name, Customer_Middle_Name, Suffix, Phone, Email_Address, First_Seen_Date, Customer_Address_Street1, Customer_Address_City, Customer_Address_State, Customer_Address_Zip, Customer_Address_Last_Modified_Date)
VALUES (2, 'Elon', 'Marley', 'A', 'Mr', '9876543210', 'Elon.M@example.com', ('2023-APR-20'), '225 20th  St', 'BocaRaton', 'FL', '33431', ('2023-APR-20'));
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, Customer_Last_Name, Customer_First_Name, Customer_Middle_Name, Suffix, Phone, Email_Address, First_Seen_Date, Customer_Address_Street1, Customer_Address_City, Customer_Address_State, Customer_Address_Zip, Customer_Address_Last_Modified_Date)
VALUES (3, 'Bill', 'Door', 'B', 'Mr', '5554443333', 'Bill.D@example.com', ('2023-APR-10'), '3100 Lionshead St', 'BocaRaton', 'FL', '33431', ('2023-APR-10'));
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, Customer_Last_Name, Customer_First_Name, Customer_Middle_Name, Suffix, Phone, Email_Address, First_Seen_Date, Customer_Address_Street1, Customer_Address_City, Customer_Address_State, Customer_Address_Zip, Customer_Address_Last_Modified_Date)
VALUES (4, 'Mark', 'Musk', 'C', 'Jr', '2223334444', 'Mark.M@example.com', ('2023-APR-05'), '1201 N Dixie Hwy', 'BocaRaton', 'FL', '33431', ('2023-APR-05'));
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, Customer_Last_Name, Customer_First_Name, Customer_Middle_Name, Suffix, Phone, Email_Address, First_Seen_Date, Customer_Address_Street1, Customer_Address_City, Customer_Address_State, Customer_Address_Zip, Customer_Address_Last_Modified_Date)
VALUES (5, 'Bill', 'Ackman', 'B', 'Sir', '1112223333', 'Bill.A@example.com', ('2023-APR-15'), '555 Cedar St', 'BocaRaton', 'FL', '33431', ('2023-APR-15'));
```

Comment: Later versions of Oracle (23c) *do* support the `INSERT INTO .... (...) VALUES (....), (....)` syntax. I think you meant "Earlier versions" (before 23c).

Comment: Also, `'2023-APR-15'` is not a date data-type. It is a string literal that looks like a date and Oracle will try to perform an implicit conversion from a string-to-date using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model; that conversion may or may not succeed but every user can modify their NLS parameters at any time so you cannot rely on two users having the same NLS parameter settings or even for the same user to have consistent NLS settings so it is better to never rely on implicit casts and use either a date literal (i.e. `DATE '2023-02-15'`) or `TO_DATE`.